# HttpClient Time_wait

Tags: httpclient, influxdb

I make connector from unity to influxdb using HttpClient. but this problum it was so angre, how can i do this code edit? I learned c# 3weeks ago.... i tryed
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

but many more new create tcp... time_wait

[image]

this is my code

code 1

```
public async Task GetPositionAsync()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Url))
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                 getdata = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
    }

    client.Dispose();
}
```

code 2

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    int refreshTime = 5;

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token " + token);
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/csv");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

    var fluxQuery = "from(bucket: \"DT_Object\")\n"
                   + "|> range(start: -6h)"
                   + "|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_measurement\"] ==\" NPC\")"
                   + "|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"NAME\"] == \"NPC\")"
                   + "|> filter(fn: (r) => r[\"_field\"] == \"X\" or r[\"_field\"] == \"Y\" or r[\"_field\"] == \"Z\")"
                   + "|> aggregateWindow(every: " + refreshTime + "s, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)"
                   + "|> yield(name: \"mean\")";

    var data = new StringContent(fluxQuery, Encoding.UTF8, "application/vnd.flux");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, data);
    Debug.Log(response);
    // var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync(requestUrl);
    // Debug.Log("get data : " + responseString);
    //response.Content = "application/CSV";
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    Debug.Log("데이터 읽어줘 " + result.ToString());

    if (result == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("결과없음");
    }

    Debug.Log("result : " + result);



    client.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to [reuse `HttpClient`](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/):

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new();
public async Task GetPositionAsync()
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Url))
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
             getdata = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u friend but, this HttpClient client = new(); tuple error... end  modifiyd

Comment: Thanks to a friend. but this HttpClient client = new(); tuple error, ... so modifiy HttpClient client = new HttpClient (); C# have multithreadconnectmanager?? and    did you know one class in two other job client create code?

Comment: @user15351791: `HttpClient` is designed to be used safely from multiple threads at the same time.